# Choosing dates from present to future in HTML5

Tags: html

I have an input type date which is where i choose the date. I want the dates that can be chosen are the dates from the present times to the future i dont want times from the past. How can i do that?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date.attrs.min

Answer (score 0):

Just do this, Put it in a function and run it on button click.

```
<input type="date" id="date1" name="bday">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var valDate = document.querySelector("date1");
    var date = "";
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd
    } 

    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm
    } 

    today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
            today = today.split('/');
            date = valDate.value.split('/');
            if(parseInt(date)<parseInt(today)){
                alert("please enter the date in the future or present not the past");
            }
  </script>
```